# How do I add a variable to File Location vbscript/html

Tags: html, vbscript, hta

This is the vbs. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
Sub Window_onLoad 
    Set objSysInfo = CreateObject( "WinNTSystemInfo" )
    strUserName = objSysInfo.UserName
End Sub
Sub OpenCP
   CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("""C:\Users\" & strUserName & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools\Control Panel.lnk""")
End Sub
```

Here's how I'm accessing the sub.

```
<input type="button" value="Open Control Panel" name="open_cp" onClick="OpenCP" id="button">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "control"
```

is all you need do.

Comment: thats great! How would i do the variable way still for other paths.

Comment: Your code is ok, but you've made assumptions. IE is the user's folder the same as their name? You can get their folder either by expanding environment strings (%userprofile%). OR msgbox CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(&h10).self.path. AppData folder is 0x1a and 0x1c, profile is 0x28, startmenu is 0xb

Comment: i found another way i just threw the subs together that was my problem, I cant get the sub to call inside another sub idk if its possible, also i tried using %USERNAME% like in a bat file but that doesnt work for all machines for some reason

Comment: strusername is a local variable. so dim it outside of a sub or function. That makes it a global.